# create OOP using foreach

Tags: wordpress, oop, widget

I want to register widgets using foreach

```
$widgets['Gallery'] = array(
        'title' => __('Gallery', 'redux-framework'),
        'desc' => __('Creates a custom gallery', 'redux-framework'),
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 'ids',
                'type' => 'gallery',
                'title' => __('Add/Edit Gallery', 'redux-framework'),
                'subtitle' => __('Create a new Gallery by selecting existing or uploading new images', 'redux-framework'),
            ),
        )
    );
$widgets['textblock'] = array(
    'title' => __('Text Block', 'redux-framework'),
    'desc' => __('Create a simple block text.', 'redux-framework'),
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'content',
            'type' => 'editor',
            'title' => __('Content', 'redux-framework'),
            'subtitle' => __('Enter some content for this textblock', 'redux-framework'),
        ),
    )
);
    foreach ($widgets as $class => $field) {
                $class = str_replace('-', '_', $class);
                class $class extends Cadr_Widget {
                    //the rest of methods here
                }
                if (class_exists($class))
                    register_widget($class);    
            }
```

is it possible to do some thing like this ??
I'm receiving error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING in C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\theme\wp-content\themes\cadr-master\framework\builder\inc\core.php on line 424

without define class inside foreach , I must I write every class and I have a lot of widgets

```
class Gallery extends cadr_Widget {

    /**
     * Render the widget in frontend
     *
     * @param array $args
     * @param array $instance
     * @return bool|void
     */
    function widget($args, $instance) {
        //echo $instance['content'];
    }

}
```

Comment: What possible reason would you have for trying to do this?  It is doing nothing other than creating numerous class definitions all of which would have the exact same code?  Classes are blueprints for objects... so it would seem that you would simply want to create a number of objects at some point.

Comment: And a Widget is something that replicates itself in the application. Why would you need to duplicate the class? This only makes sense if they were completely different Widgets.

Comment: it's completely different widgets and different classes